# Find sites hosted together?

Tags: web-server, domain, ip

Would i be able to look up my server IP and find all the site hosted under it? Is there another way to find a group of sites? perhaps not using their IP?

Answer (score 1):

An easy one I tried a few minutes ago is http://domainsbyip.com/

It did actually list every domain I had hosted on my server. So it must be doing something right.

Comment: Weird that it worked for you. It didn't for me. I'm running several web sites on a dynamic ip address using IIS and host headers. Any idea how that site determines the web sites on a particular ip address?